# How I debug why a page without Javascript DOM is wildly different from the source?

Tags: html, dom

I have a webpage that even with any JS in the source itself removed, and Javascript disabled on the browser, when loaded the DOM has lots of tags that I didn't put there, most notoriously on Chrome some spam of  tags, sometimes there are chains of 4 or 5  nested, and then my actual content nested inside.

How I figure why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe a browser extension? Try a clean profile, maybe reinstall the browser too.

Comment: post your original code, and the the rendered code, so we can compare

Comment: I asked "how", not an actual solution. what happen if this problem bite me again in the future for a different reason?